# The external central product of multiple groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A, B \le G$ be two subgroups whose elements commute, then $A \cap B \le Z(AB)$
and the group $AB$ is called the *internal central product* of $A$ and $B$. Likeweise there exists an external central product, given by two groups $A, B$ with subgroups $A_1 \le Z(A), B_1 \le Z(B)$ and an isomorphism $\theta : A_1 \to B_1$, then the external central product is the cartesian product of $A$ and $B$ modulo the subgroup $\{ (x, \theta(x)^{-1}) : x \in A_1 \}$, i.e. we identify $x$ with its image. The internal central product is isomorphic to the external central product via $\operatorname{id} : A \cap B \to A \cap B$. It is easy to show that
$$
 AB / (A\cap B) \cong A / (A\cap B) \times A / (A\cap B).
$$

These notions could be found [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_product), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418400/properties-about-central-product).

But what is the central product of more than two groups, internally and externally, and what properties does it have?

For the internal central product I found in [Kurzweil/Stellmacher](https://books.google.com.ai/books?id=6foucBXceC4C&lpg=PR1&hl=de&pg=PA32#v=onepage&q&f=false) a definition. For three subgroups $A,B,C \le G$ whose elements pairwise commute, it is simply $ABC$.

But what is an equivalent external construction? What and how should be identified in the respective centers?

Note that $A\cap B \cap C \le Z(ABC)$, but also $AB \cap C, A \cap BC, AB\cap C$ are all contained in the center of $ABC$ (and it is in general bigger), hence their product is contained in $Z(ABC)$.

For two groups it is clear that $A\cap B$ gets identified, but what is identified on the cartesian product if we take three subgroups? A natural candidate would be $A \cap B \cap C$, so I suppose three isomorphisms $A_1 \le Z(A), B_1 \le Z(B), C_1 \le Z(C)$ with $\theta_1 : A_1 \to B_1, \theta_2 : A_1 \to C_1, \theta_3 : B_1 \to C_1$. But what factor group do we have to factor out? And how to make the construction such that associativity is preserved (at least up to isomorphism)?

EDIT: As pointed out by Derek Holt in the comments demanding that $\theta_2$ is the composite of $\theta_1$ and $\theta_3$ would give a valid identification by factoring out
the normal subgroup generated by
$$
  \{ (a, \theta_1(a)^{-1}) : a \in A_1\}, \quad
  \{ (b, \theta_3(a)^{-1}) : b \in B_1\}
$$
in the cartesian product group of $A,B$ and $C$. Then the identification $\theta_1(a) = \theta_2(a)$ would be implied and the common subgroup is their intersection.
But still this assumes we start out from three groups with three isomorphisms from the start, but is there any way to define an external central product $A \star_{central} B$ such that
$$
 (A \star_{central} B) \star_{central} C
 \cong A \star_{central} ( B \star_{central} C ).
$$
What isomorphism to choose from $A \star_{central} B$ to $C$ for example?

Comment: Your first sentence only makes sense if $A$ and $B$ are both subgroups of some common overgroup.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you, fixed that!

Comment: Also, near the end, I think you need to assume that $\theta_2$ is the composite of $\theta_1$ and $\theta_3$. Then the identifications are consistent.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks, that seems to work. But I still have some issues how to define an external central product such that the associative law holds...

Comment: I would expect a definition similar to the definition given for arbitrary amalgamated free product, where you specify an isomorphism $\theta_{ij}$ between subgroup $H_i\leq A_i$ and $H_j\leq A_j$, requiring $\theta_{ii}=\mathrm{id}$, $\theta_{ji}=\theta_{ij}^{-1}$, and requiring the "triple intersections" to match up: for all $i,j,k$, $\theta_{ij}|_{H_i\cap H_k} = \theta_{ik}|_{H_i\cap H_j}$. Then you consider the direct product modulo the subgroup generated by all the correspondences. But this may not work for arbitrary families, just as it doesn't always work in the free case.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That is new stuff for me, do you have any further reference? And in your "triple intersection" formula are the indices right. Should both isomorphisms not restricted to the same domain?

Comment: @StefanH Yes, sorry. The material is in Hannah Neumann's doctoral thesis. Let me see if I can dig it out from her relevant paper...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm used to central products requiring isomorphic centers, and then asking that all the isomorphisms be compatible. So given a family $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$, you would have isomorphisms $\theta_{ij}\colon Z(A_i)\to Z(A_j)$, and require $\theta_{ii}=\mathrm{id}_{Z(A_i)}$, $\theta_{ji}=\theta_{ij}^{-1}$, and $\theta_{ik}=\theta_{jk}\circ\theta_{ij}$ for all $i,j,k$. Then you would take the group $\prod_{i\in I}A_i/N$, where $N$ is generated by all elements identifying $a_i\in Z(A_i)$ with $\theta_{ij}(a_i)$ in $Z(A_j)$.

Alternatively, one could generalize the definition following the same lines as Hanna Neumann did for the generalized free product with amalgamation (Neumann, Hanna. *Generalized Free Products with Amalgamated Subgroups.* American Journal of Mathematics, vol. 70, no. 3, 1948, pp. 590–625. [JSTOR link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372201); and  *Generalized free products with amalgamated subgroups*, Amer. J. Math. vol. 72, no. 3 (Jul 1949), pp. 491-540, [JSTOR link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372346) ). Let $\{G_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of groups, and for each $i,j\in I$ let $A_{ij}\leq Z(G_i)$ be specified, with isomorphisms $\theta_{ij}\colon A_{ij}\to A_{ji}$ such that $\theta_{ij}=\theta_{ji}^{-1}$, and $\theta_{ii}=\mathrm{id}$. We say a group $G$ is the central product of the $G_i$ at the $A_{ij}$ if and only there exist embeddings $f_i\colon G_i\to G$ such that

- $G=\langle f_i(G_i)\mid i\in I\rangle$,
- $f_i(G_i)\cap f_j(G_j)=f_i(A_{ij})$,
- $f_i|_{A_{ij}} = f_j\circ \theta_{ij}|_{A_{ij}}$,
- If $i\neq j$, $a\in G_i$ and $b\in G_j$, then $f_i(a)$ commutes with $f_j(b)$.

A necessary condition for this to work is that if $i,j,k$ are three indices, then $f_{i}(A_{ij}\cap A_{ik})$ be identified with $f_j(A_{ji}\cap A_{jk})$, with $f_k(A_{ki}\cap A_{kj})$, and that the identification be such that $\theta_{ik}|_{A_{ij}\cap A_{ik}} = \theta_{jk}\circ\theta_{ij}|_{A_{ij}\cap A_{ik}}$.